# is there a consistent patch timeline with RHEL, like first of month?

Tags: rhel, software-updates

With the mindset of *a work environment and linux servers need to be patched regularly for security reasons*

does RHEL (for version 7) have any kind of patch frequency or timeline?

Such that people more in the loop than I expect updates (kernel updates?) happen on the first week of every month or something like that?  Or do they just roll out after whenever they do?  I ask because in putting together a work schedule it's easy to remember that first week of every month we do our patching but I don't want that to coincide to be immediately after [kernel] updates such that I'm one of the first people to use it and experience possible problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red Hat doesn't have a fixed timeline for when it releases patches, security updates, or new features. It simply releases them as they become available. The same is true for CentOS.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3711551